# How to make 2 remote tables in sync along with determination of Delta records

Tags: sql, sql-server, informatica

We have 10 tables on vendor system and same 10 tables on our DB side along with 10 _HISTORIC tables i.e. for each table in order to capture updated/new records.

We are reading the main tables from Vendor system using Informatica to truncate and load into our tables. How do we find Delta records without using Triggers and CDC as it comes with cost on vendor system.

4 tables are such that which have 200 columns and records around 31K in each with expectation that 100-500 records might update daily.
We are using Left Join in Informatica to load new Records in our Main and _HISTORIC tables.

But what's efficient approach to find the Updated records of Vendor table and load them in our _HISTORIC table ?

For new Records using query :

```
-- NEW RECORDS
INSERT INTO TABLEA_HISTORIC
SELECT FROM TABLEA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB
ON A.PK = B.PK
WHERE B.PK IS NULL
```

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is generally more efficient. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does "How do we find Delta records without using Triggers and CDC as it comes with cost on vendor system." mean? are you saying the vendor won't let you do this? What type of datbase is the source, is it SQL Server

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Source system belongs to vendor , any changes in dB modeling comes with heavy dollars. Hence we just to want to read the source and do everything on our side. Both source and Destination is MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Charlieface : how to find updated records i.e. if any column got updated in table.

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of `MERGE`, you need to know the primary key to be able to match records

Answer (score 0):

I believe a system versioned temporary table will be something you are looking for here. You can create a system versioned table for any table in SQL server 2016 or later.

for example, say I have a table Employee

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmployeeId VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
EmployeeName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
EmployeeDOJ DATE,
ValidFrom datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,--Automatically updated by the system when the row is updated
ValidTo datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,--auto-updated
 PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)--to set the row validity period
)
```

the column ValidFrom, ValidTo determines the time period on which that particular row was active.

For More Info refer the micorsoft article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Create staging tables, load wipe&load them. Next, use them for finding the differences that need to be load into your target tables.

The CDC logic needs to be performed this way, but it will not affect your source system.

Another way - not sure if possible in your case - is to load partial data based on some source system date or key. This way you stage only the new data. This improves performance a lot, but makes finding the deletes in source impossible.

Answer (score 0):

A. To replicate a smaller subset of records in the source without making schema changes, there are a few options.

1. Transactional Replication, however this is not very flexible. For example would not allow any differences in the target database, and therefore is not a solution for you.
2. Identify a "date modified" field in the source. This obviously has to already exist, and will not allow you to identify deletes
3. Use a "windowing approach" where you simply delete and reload the last months transactions, again based on an existing date. Requires an existing date that isn't back dated and doesn't work for non transactional tables (which are usually small enough to just do full copies anyway)
4. Turn on change tracking. Your vendor may or may not argue that tihs is a costly change (it isn't) or impacts application performance (it probably doesn't)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Turning on change tracking will allow you to more easily identify changes to all tables.

You need to ask yourself: is it really an issue to copy the entire table? I have built solutions that simple copy entire large tables (*far* larger than 31k records) every hour and there is never an issue.

You need to consider what complications you introduce by building an incremental solution, and whether the associated maintenance and complexity is worth being able to reduce a record copy from 31K (full table) to 500 records (changed). Again a full copy of 31K records is actually pretty fast under normal circumstances (like 10 seconds or so)

B. Target table

As already recommended by many, you might want to consider a temporal table, although if you *do* decide to do full copies, a temporal table might not be the beast option.